# How to make Siri set an alarm AND name/label the alarm at same time?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, alarm

How can I make iOS's Siri set an alarm AND name/label the alarm at same time?

I set many alarms on my iPhone5S running iOS7, and sometimes it's hard to remember what I set them for when they go off.  With a label I'm reminded the purpose (of the alarm).  I don't want to take time to manually edit the alarm after Siri sets it--that's what I want Siri to do for me.

Some discussion [here](http://www.howardforums.com/showthread.php/1793918-Siri-setting-alarm) with apparently no clear answer, or at least nothing that yet works reliably on my phone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly say this:

> Set alarm for [time] labeled [insert name here]

This works for me every time, thus it should work for your appointments or alarms too. Make sure you say labeled right: click here for the [pronunciation](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=labeled&submit=Submit) and
just make sure the names aren't too long.

Names I've tried:

1. Hello
2. Triangle
3. Square

Comment: Works consistently for me, thx.  Many-word labels _usually_ work but get more problematic as sentences get longer.  Very workable in any case.

Comment: Not working for me in iOS 8. Alarm is set with no description.

Answer (score 5):

You can also have Siri set reminders for you, in the Reminders app, instead of alarms.

> Remind me at *time* to *task*.

It also works for geofenced reminders:

> Remind me when I get home to *task*.
>
> Remind me when I leave here to *task*.

This right here is easily 75% of what I use Siri for, and I find it's a more fitting solution than using alarms—in my mind, alarms are for waking up.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point to something that shows where Reminder.app msgs get sent... and/or the difference between iOS Reminders and Alarms? I had trouble easily finding this.

Comment: Sent or set?  They get set in the Reminders app, and sent as a notification.

Comment: Sent. But your answer is helpful for both ("sent" and "set"), thx.

Comment: Just  remember to turn notifications on for the Reminders app! Settings > Notifications > Reminders.

Answer (score 2):

I found the best way is to say "Set an alarm for [time] and label it [your label here].

Comment: Nice - tenses and Siri are about as good as tenses and autocorrect :)

Comment: Also found that if you don't already have an alarm at that time you have to say "Create" an alarm for [time] and label it [your label here].
Otherwise she argues with you that you don't have an alarm set for [time].

Answer (score 0):

Heads up though...if you set a reminder, it can synch with your other Mac devices--causing a reminder to pop up on those too. A factor for me, since I've had a reminder to, say, call the divorce lawyer....and then this pops up on the desktop mac in front of the kiddos. If I'd prefer a reminder be JUST to me, I'll use the alarm instead.

Comment: Granted, that's a concern, but for Macs you can avoid it by using different user accounts and only signing in to your iCloud account on your user account.  (For iOS, I don't believe there's a way around it.)

Answer (score 0):

To make your reminders just appear in your own cloud when using family sharing I found a trick

Go to reminders, hit the plus icon and make a new list in a different colour and label it.

Then go to reminders in settings and change the default list to that one setting it to non family share.

That will be the reminder list that Siri will go to

Answer (score 0):

*"Hey Siri, Set a XXXX alarm for YY o'clock"* will set an alarm with the label "XXXX".

I assume you want an Alarm, and not a Reminder (many of the answers here are about Reminders)